# Cmake Error on Manjaro: CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT

Tags: linux, cmake, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I'm getting this error on Manjaro when trying to run *cmake ..* in a folder:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

cmake version 3.25.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I've installed cmake through *sudo pamac install base-devel* and I normally use clion, pointing to */usr/bin/cmake* instead of the bundled cmake. I've tried using *export CMAKE_ROOT=/usr/share/cmake* as well as *export CMAKE_ROOT=/usr/bin/cmake* and sourcing my bashrc file and it still shows the same error. I've uninstalled cmake and reinstalled it, and still no-go. I've tried to run the command using */usr/bin/cmake* and it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try installing CMake with: `sudo snap install cmake --classic`. Then check `cmake` works from the command line. CLion should show it has found a CMake in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains`.

Comment: Directory pointed by `CMAKE_ROOT` variable should be the one containing `Modules` subdirectory.

Comment: If you have a package bug, report a bug to the package maintainers.

Comment: @rturrado using the snap cmake worked, thanks!